# Mysql has a socket failure

Tags: php, mysql, database, debian, raspberry-pi

mysql is currently showing

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

when i try to logon at the moment. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: ^ suggest you go through the same steps he did, before looking at the answers

Comment: The other answer didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to kill the socket with (this may depend on your OS)

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
rm: remove socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'? y
```

restart the service

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': No such file or directory